# Achad Asar Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows two hundred eleven?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The beams that were used to build the Mishkan were taken from trees planted in Egypt by Yaakov Avinu ([Rashi to Exodus 26:15](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9887/showrashi/true#v2615)). Since Yaakov came down in the year 2238 and the Mishkan was constructed in 2449, these trees waited 211 years to be used for their ultimate purpose.

Comment: ...assuming he planted them as soon as he got there. Rashi says _nata_ (not _zara_), which I _think_ means "transplanted" (an existing tree, as opposed to planting a seed), right? In that case, presumably he did it on arrival.

Answer (score 1):

Nebuzaradan, the chief executioner, slew 211 myriads. - Gittin 57b (Encyclopedia of Biblical Personalities, p. 401)

Answer (score 0):

Jews wear a Yarmulke on their head which in Yiddish is known as a (קאפל) Kapel

The reason we wear a קאפל is to show that we fear Hashem

קאפל & ירא both = 211

Answer (score 0):

211 are the verses in [Zechariah](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t23.htm).​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​